# css - how to get (responsive) li's with the same height when they have a different width?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my current scenario:

- I have a row with 4 li elements and each has a bootstrap 'col-xs-3'
  class so that each element occupies the same space within that row
- I also gave the elements 5px padding on each side
- I removed the left padding of the first li and the right padding of the last li
- All li's contain one image and all images have the same size (width: 800, height: 600)

The problem:

- Due to the padding difference, li 2 and li 3 (which have more
  padding), become wider and therefore, they get a different height,
  which is visible when you look at the images

[image]

Is there a way to have responsive li's (and images) with the same height when there's this width difference? Thanks in advance!

HTML:

```
<div id="other-posts-container" class="col-xs-12 no-padding">
    <h3 class="title col-xs-12 no-padding">Title here</h3>
    <ul id="dont-miss-posts" class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <li class="col-xs-3 no-padding">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/post-1.png">
                    <p class="post-title">Sushi de qualidade fora do centro de Lisboa</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="col-xs-3 no-padding">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="img/post-2.png">
                    <p class="post-title">Sushi de qualidade fora do centro de Lisboa</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            etc
```

CSS:

```
#other-posts-container li {
    padding: 0 5px;
}

#other-posts-container li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#other-posts-container li:nth-of-type(1) {
    padding-left: 0;
}
#other-posts-container li:nth-of-type(4) {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your row inside container Bootstrap class or you want full width?

Comment: I don't quite get what you're asking. I'm using 'container-fluid' and then I don't have rows, just columns (I know I should probably use rows). Those columns have the 'col-xs-12' class but also contain padding on the sides. Check the image I added to the post to get a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your HTML structure is not correct (you don't you `rows` properly, `div` is not allowed as a direct child of `ul` and you use `col-xs-12` inside `col-xs-12`). My HTML solution:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" class="img-responsive">
        <p>Sushi de qualidade fora do centro de Lisboa</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" class="img-responsive">
        <p>Sushi de qualidade fora do centro de Lisboa</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" class="img-responsive">
        <p>Sushi de qualidade fora do centro de Lisboa</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <a href="">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/800x600" class="img-responsive">
        <p>Sushi de qualidade fora do centro de Lisboa</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. You can set padding for all your items and add negative margin to `row` (to properly align whole container).

```
.row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/ORpqLE)

Comment: Your code works, thank you! Just a question, why does a horizontal scrollbar show up in the second example, with the container-fluid class and no padding (img » http://postimg.org/image/9035yw413/)? I noticed it disappears (as well as the extra space) if I remove the 'without padding' class.

Comment: This is because of the padding of the first and last items, I added `overflow-x: hidden` to the Codepen to solve that.

Comment: Ahh got it. Thanks! :)
Also, to the other person who posted an answer (it got/was deleted for some reason): I was still checking if it worked..thank you anyway.